# SCGI scripting engine servers? (C#, Java, PHP)

Tags: c#, java, php, scgi

I am looking for scripting engines that provide an SCGI server:

- a server like Apache receives HTTP requests and sends them to the backend scripting engine,
- the scripting engine parses and process the SCGI request and sends the reply to Apache,
- Apache sends the reply to the client.

I've an interest in using C#, Java and PHP (any of those three) and would like to find relevant resources (not only links to code but also how-to's in order to make this all work toguether).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The current state of these interfaces is very limited today.

It seems that the mainstream players do not like SCGI.
That may be because SCGI is so much faster than fastCGI...

I am affraid that developers will have to do it -for their 
own good.